# 'this' inside prototype method not resolving as expected when inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, prototype, this

I have a constructor which is an extension of a module (https://github.com/fluxxu/evalidator) in node.js. **This extended constructor defines two more methods in the prototype, and **method B** calls method A via 'this' keyword**. This constructor is used to initialize a property in another object, and when i invoke the method B from this property i get an error like 'main object' doesn't have method A:

```
TypeError: Object function (){ superEvalidatorVar.method_B(); } 
has no method 'method_B' at Object.<anonymous>
```

Here is the code:

```
var EValidator = require('evalidator');


/**
 * EValidator extension object
 * @constructor
 */
function SuperEValidator(){
    // EValidator Inheritance
    EValidator.apply(this, arguments);
}

SuperEValidator.prototype = Object.create(EValidator.prototype);
SuperEValidator.prototype.constructor = SuperEValidator;

SuperEValidator.prototype.method_A = function(){
    console.log('method_A called');
};

SuperEValidator.prototype.method_B = function(){
    this.method_A();
};

var superEvalidatorVar = new SuperEValidator();

var mainObject = {
    callingSuperEValidator: function(){
        superEvalidatorVar.method_B();
    }
};

/*** Calling methods from MainObject ***/
mainObject.callingSuperEValidator.method_B(); // Throws Error!
```

**The 'this' keyword at method_B of the extended constructor resolves to mainObject, why??

1. Set var me; at global level and set it to 'this' at PropertyObject Constructor, then inside method_B use 'me' instead 'this'.
2. Inside method_B use 'PropertyObject.prototype' instead 'this'

But i wonder if there's something bad happen i don't understand this behavior in SuperEValidator

**EDIT:**

The real purpose of all this is to rewrite the 'validate' method of a Mongoose Schema:

```
PostSchema.methods.validate = function(cb){

    // 'this' will have the value of the object (model) from which the function will be called
    evPost.validate_super(this, cb);

};
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this - everything has to do with the calling context, methods are not "object bound".

Comment: Thank you i already rode this but i still confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is not due to `this`, `this` is exactly adhere to ev.

the problem is you create ev first with `ev.__proto__==={}` and then reassign `SuperEValidator.prototype` which break the link from `ev.__proto__` and `SuperEvalidator.prototype`.

notice that here function declaration for SuperEValidator is hoisting but not for prototype define. so just simply move your mainObject to bottom to solve the problem.

```
var mainObject = {
    propertyObject: new PropertyObject(),
    ev: new SuperEValidator() // at the moment, ev.__proto__ === {}
};
...
// SuperEValidator.prototype has been assigned to another reference while ev.__proto__ is still {}
SuperEValidator.prototype = Object.create(EValidator.prototype);
```

Comment: Uhmmm that's true, but actually my problem is something more tricky. I edit the post to show it.

Comment: `callingSuperEValidator` is a function, why append `.method_B()` to it?

Comment: Uhm this is not the real code i just tried to abstract everything to the code posted above, basically i wanted to rewrite a method. I edit to express it.

Comment: well, actually it's the same problem as i stated. `var superEvalidatorVar = new SuperEValidator();` you do this before you reassign `SuperEValidator.prototype`. You need to create SuperEValidator object later after you reassign the prototype.

Comment: `mainObject.callingSuperEValidator.method_B();` should be `mainObject.callingSuperEValidator()`......

Comment: That works.. yes... sorry for the mistake... anyway in real code still giving me the error. I edit once again

Comment: it will be easy to locate the problem if you could advise which file and which line causing the error. anyway it might takes a while to look into the whole source. could you pls upvote/accept the answer?

Comment: Of course man, i found finally the answer, the EValidator module change the 'this' scope explicitly with a 'call/apply'. Actually all code above works, thanks to you i could reach the answer. Thank you thank you very much, can i buy you a beer?

Comment: Haha yea, let me know if you ever come :P